# What is a Pythonic way to get the exact same product for two arrays x and y, where y is x arbitrarily shuffled?

Tags: python, numpy, math, precision, int64

I am trying to get the same result when I apply say some function product function prod(x) to x and shuffle(x) where x is some arbitrary array of integers say up to length 100,  prod(x) is an function that returns the product of the entries of x, and shuffle is a function that returns  x, shuffled.

i.e.

I want prod(x) == prod(shuffle(x)) to be True

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is a more tangible question how can I get True below?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(100, 1000, 10)

x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float64)

xs = np.copy(x)

np.random.shuffle(xs)

y = np.prod(x)

ys = np.prod(xs)

print(y)

print(ys)

print(ys == y)
```

Comment: `x * np.random.permutation(x)`

Comment: Do you mean the element wise product of an array with a random shuffle of the same array? If yes then you could possibly reword the question and if not then please reword the question to clarify.

Comment: I mean the I want prod(x) == prod(shuffle(x)) to be True

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what product you mean. If you just want the product of the elements of the array, then the order doesn't matter if your multiplication operator is commutative. E.g., `1 * 2 * 3 == 3 * 1 * 2`.

Comment: Order does matter if the numbers are too big.

Comment: This is happening due to a very large float. You can try to compare the log of products. `np.log(y)==np.log(ys)`

Comment: I want to get a uniform result no matter what order I give the vector in.

Comment: Sort both arrays first (or reorder then in the same way): `np.prod(np.sort(x))==np.prod(np.sort(xs))`.  (I have to run your sample code multiple times to get a mix of True and False).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have precision problem, why don't you use `np.close` to check within a tolerance rather than exact equality:

```
#replace (ys == y) with:
np.isclose(ys, y, rtol=1e-15, equal_nan=True)
```

`rtol=1e-10` is relative tolerance (you can set it to your desired *relative* error, I recommend to set it to 15 or less (around 6 bytes=48 bits, I think float64 uses 52 bits for mantissa but I am not sure)). You can use `atol` argument for absolute tolerance instead of relative tolerance. `equal_nan=True` considers `NaN`s as equal (Set to `False` it you want `nan`s to be considered not equal).

Comment: The thing is I want the exact product every time not some approximation. I am currently thinking of converting to some fractional representation then converting back to an integer.

Comment: @Sergio Unless you want to use a different dtype, I am not sure if you can achieve that given the nature of precision in float64. If your numbers are too large at the end, the multiplication will not save exact number, let alone compare. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, sorting and comparing might be a better idea than simply multiplying